# java - Combining two variables to get the name of the third?

Tags: java, variables, reflection

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
int x_1 = 1;
int x_2 = 2;

String s1 = "x";
String s2 = "_1";
```

`s1` & `s2` would be variables from the user or from a loop and I want to be able to call the right `int` variable by doing something like `(s1+s2)`.

Is it possible?

Comment: The simplest way would be by reflection...which is still complicated...Might I ask *why* you want to do this? There are a number of different ways to achieve the same thing without needing to "find" variables

Comment: Shouldn't that be <force>This isn't the solution you're looking for</force> ;)

Comment: why: because i wanted a simple solution instead of using maps and hashmaps, which i used, and i thought there's a simple way of doing it (seems there is in ruby according to one of the answers :)

Comment: Reflection is not simple, nor is it fast. It also has a really nasty side effect of basically allowing direct access to private and protected methods/fields you shouldn't have access to. It also servery complicates debugging. Now I use reflection a lot to make my life easier with syncing `Threads` in `Swing`, but I'd still not recommend it in this context...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can use `Map` do this.

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("x_1",1);
map.put("x_2",2);
String s1 = "x";
String s2 = "_1";
map.get(s1+s2);
```

Comment: +1. This would be my approach. Much cleaner and easier to understand / change in the future.

Comment: Did something like this, wanted to KISS it without maps. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you need to be able to find a field within an instance of an `Object`

Something like...

```
Class clazz = obj.getClass();
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(name);
```

You can then use the `Field.setInt(Object, int)` and `Field.getInt(Object)` methods to retrieve the values.

You might like to have a read through [The Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Reflection doesn't have to be complicated.  Have a look at [beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/).  For that to work the variables would need to be part of an object, not just local variables.  Something like [PropertyUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getSimpleProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Hashtable<String,Integer>` to store the name pairs like `["x_1", 1]`.
You can easily then construct your string, get its value and use it.